# Eager loading foreign table results in null

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-5

I have a one to many relationship (Category has many Item) which I would like to eager load. Unfortunately this results in NULL. 
I am new to Laravel and after reading the documentation I am not sure what I am doing wrong.

I would appreciate a nudge in the right direction and if needed I can post the migrations too.

**dd($items)**

```
Collection {#179 ▼
  #items: array:2 [▼
    0 => Item {#176 ▼
      #fillable: array:4 [▶]
      #connection: null
      #table: null
      #primaryKey: "id"
      #perPage: 15
      +incrementing: true
      +timestamps: true
      #attributes: array:8 [▶]
      #original: array:8 [▶]
      #relations: array:1 [▼
        "category" => null      <---- HERE --------<
      ]
      #hidden: []
      #visible: []
      #appends: []
      #guarded: array:1 [▶]
      #dates: []
      #dateFormat: null
      #casts: []
      #touches: []
      #observables: []
      #with: []
      #morphClass: null
      +exists: true
      +wasRecentlyCreated: false
    }
    1 => Item {#177 ▶}
  ]
}
```

**ItemsController**

```
public function index() {
   $items = Item::with('category')->get();

   return View::make('items.index')
   ->with('items', $items);
}
```

**Item Model**

```
class Item extends Model {
    protected $fillable = array('name', 'description', 'purchased_at', 'price');
    ...
    public function category() {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Category');
    }
}
```

**Category Model**

```
class Category extends Model {
    protected $fillable = array('name');
    ...

    public function items() {
      return $this->hasMany('App\Item');
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The item has no category_id. it's also missing from the fillable array so it may just not be getting set when you create it.

Comment: The 'item_category' is being populated with a valid category id in my MySQL database when I create an Item. I have added item_category to the fillable array, but result stays the same.

Comment: item_category and category_id are not the same, based on the method name "category" laravel will use category_id, id you want to use a different field then just pass it as the second parameter to belongsTo